# Sum over all subsets in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Given a number 'c' and a list of numbers 'numbers', I am trying to generate all the sums I can have of c and any subset in numbers.
eg. (1,[2,4,8]), I should generate (note that we should always have c in a sum)
[1,3,5,9,7,11,13,15]

I wrote the following code, but not all sums appear. What is wrong?

```
function result = allsums(c, numbers)
    if isempty(numbers)
        result = [];
    else
        [nr n_numbers] = size(numbers);
        for i = 1:n_numbers
            result = cat(2, c+numbers(i), allsums(c, cat(2,numbers(1:i-1),numbers(i+1:end))));
        end
    end

result = cat(2, result, c+sum(numbers,2));
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong in the line:

```
result = cat(2, sums, c+sum(numbers,2));
```

Because you recalled function `sums` without input arguments, while you wrote the function with 2 input arguments.

UPDATE:

if `length(numbers)` less than 15 (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html), you can try `nchoosek` like this:

```
function result = sums(c, numbers)
  result = [];
  if ~isempty(numbers)
    [nr n_numbers] = size(numbers);
    result = c;
    for i = 1:n_numbers
      combi = nchoosek(numbers, i);
      for j = 1:size(combi, 1)
        result(end+1) = c + sum(combi(j,:));
      end
    end
  end
  result = unique(result);
end
```

p/s: just a very quick example, you can try to optimize the code, i'm not sure if using recursion like yours is better or using Matlab's built-in functions is better ...

Comment: no, sum is the matlab function to sum the elements of a matrix, 2 means sum over columns I'll edit ma code

Comment: yes, but the main error is the first `sums` in that line, cause you recalled your function without input arguments.

Comment: your code works thanks. However, I still don't understand what is wrong with my recursion...

Comment: your new code worked. you just need to use `unique(result)` to remove the duplicated values

Answer (score 3):

This could be one approach -

```
%// Input array and scalar
numbers = [2,4,8] 
c = 1;

%// Generate all sums for all combinations with nchoosek; then add up with c
combsums = arrayfun(@(n) sum(nchoosek(numbers,n),2),1:numel(numbers),'Uni',0)
result = [c ; c+vertcat(combsums{:})]
```

Code run -

```
result =
     1
     3
     5
     9
     7
    11
    13
    15
```

Comment: upvoted. I am still not getting used to replacing for-loop by arrayfun ... quite a big hammer when logical steps are too clear ...

Comment: @scmg Well with `arrayfun` it's a compact way to do stuffs. Also, when replacing loops that do heavy reductions, like `sum-reduction` in this case with `arrayfun`, it could be really interesting in terms of performance I think.

Answer (score 2):

How about a one-line solution?

```
c = 1; %// number 
S = [2 4 8]; %// set

result = unique(c+S*(dec2bin(0:2^numel(S)-1).'-'0'));
```

*Explanation*: The key here is `dec2bin(0:2^numel(S)-1).'-'0'`, which produces a `0`-`1` pattern indicating which elements of the set `S` get added. In the example this is

```
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1
 0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     1
```

Each column corresponds to a different subset of `S`. Matrix multiplication by `S` then gives the sum for each subset.

Comment: Good innovation with the combination finding using `dec2bin`!